# How to deserialize Xml from string (Xml get from chartlyrics.com)

Tags: c#, uwp, xmlserializer

I cannot deserialize string I get from chartlyrics.com. I get the result from there by next line of code:

```
string xml = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync("http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyric?artist="+Artist+"&song="+Song);
```

So far so good... But when I try to deserialize it occurs problems. During process I get error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass is
> inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be
> processed.

My classes are following:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class SearchLyricResultCollection
    {
        [XmlArray("ArrayOfSearchLyricResult")]
        [XmlArrayItem("SearchLyricResult")]
        public List<SearchLyricResult> ListOfTracks;
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class SearchLyricResult
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TrackId")]
        public string TrackId;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LyricChecksum")]
        public string LyricChecksum;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LyricId")]
        public string LyricId;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SongUrl")]
        public string SongUrl;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ArtistUrl")]
        public string ArtistUrl;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Artist")]
        public string Artist;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Song")]
        public string Song;
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SongRank")]
        public string SongRank;
    }
```

and I try to serialize using next code:

```
        //Crash just here...
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SearchLyricResultCollection));
        //Cannot continue up here...
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var result = (SearchLyricResultCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

So, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is your `SearchLyricResultCollection` class inside of any other class?

Comment: Selim Yildiz ,  really good point!  The class was inside the other class (not Public one) and that's why I had a problem.  The problem solved now.  Thanks!

Comment: I added this as an answer so that it might help the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `SearchLyricResultCollection` is probably inside the other class which is not public. So if you update that as public it should solve your problem.

See: [Public Class - "is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277605/public-class-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level-only-public-types-c)